# Tarski's conception of truth and Satisfaction

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand whether or not I should use Tarski's concept of satisfaction when defining truth for propositional languages.

More precisely, suppose that I have a denumerable set of propositional variables, and that my language consists of the two propositional connectives $\neg$ and $\vee$ only. Do I need to introduce the concept of satisfaction to define truth for this language? (My hesitation lies in the fact that I have a denumerable set of propositional variables.)

I am under the impression that satisfaction is necessary for first order languages, but not for propositional languages. I would like to know if I am correct.

Answer (score 1):

The *truth* definition for a propositional language is base on [compositionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compositionality/), using (for classical logic) the well-known truth table for the [logical connectives](https://www.iep.utm.edu/prop-log/#SH3b).

We write $1$ and $0$ instead of “true” and “false” and we write $v(\phi) = 1$ for “$\phi$ is true”.

We have that : $v(ϕ ∨ ψ) = 1$ iff $v(ϕ) =1$ or $v(ψ) = 1$ and and $v(¬ϕ) = 1 −v(ϕ)$.

Let $\text{At}$ the collection of *atoms*, i.e.  of proposition symbols: $p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots$.

We can extend a truth assignment $v : \text{At} \to \{ 0,1 \}$ to the collection $\text{Prop}$ of all propositional formulas with the following defintion:

> $v(⊥) = 0$
>
> $v(¬ϕ) = 1− v(ϕ)$
>
> $v(ϕ ∨ ψ) = \max (v(ϕ), v(ψ))$.

Now we have the usual defintions :

> $v \vDash \phi$, meaning : "truth assignment $v$ *satisfies* formula $\phi$";
>
> $\vDash \phi$, meaning : "formula $\phi$ is a *tautology*, i.e. it is satisfied by every truth assignment";
>
> $\Gamma \vDash \phi$, meaning : "$\phi$ is a *semantical* (or : *logical*) *consequence*  of the set of formulas $Γ$, i.e. $\phi$ is satisfied by every truth assignment that satisfies every formulas in $Γ$".